# Junit Test Pass even when the method called inside may fail

Tags: java, junit5

I am creating a Junit Unit Test to check the createAccount method in service that calls Service a helper method. Please find it below.

**Service class**

```
public class AccountServiceImpl {
@Autowired
AccountHelper accountHelper;

@Override
public Account createAccount(Account account) throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    accountHelper.checkAccountTypeForCustomer(account);
        return accountRepository.save(account);
}
}
```

**Helper Class:**

```
public void checkAccountTypeForCustomer(Account acc) throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    Boolean customerExists = customerRepository.existsById(acc.getCustomerId());
    if(!customerExists) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException("604", Message.CUSTOMER_NOT_FOUND);
    }   
}
```

**AccountServiceTest class**

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AccountServiceTest {

```
@Mock
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@Mock
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Mock
private AccountHelper accountHelper;

@InjectMocks 
private AccountService testService;

 @Test
 void testCreateAccount() throws CustomerNotFoundException {
      Account account = Account.builder().
        accountType(AccountType.SAVINGS).
        openingBalance(BigDecimal.valueOf(3000)).
        ifsc("IFSC1").
        customerId(1).
        build();
 testService.createAccount(account);
```

}
}

Above Test is passing although the customer is not present in the database.
The test is incomplete. But still the statement: testService.createAccount(account);
must fail as per my understanding.

Kindly correct me if I am wrong. I am relatively new to Junit.

However if I place the implementation for checkAccountTypeForCustomer() inside the service method instead of in the helper, the test case fails as expected.

Comment: How does your entire test class look like? Are the service and the repository mocked via `@MockBean`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `accountHelper` is mocked in your test, which means that invocation of `accountHelper.checkAccountTypeForCustomer(account)` doesn't execute your business code.

I recommend you to use Spring mocking in this case, and to specify how your repository is expected to behave. It would look something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class AccountServiceTest {
    @MockBean
    private CustomerRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    private AccountService testService;
    
    @Test
    void testCreateAccount() throws CustomerNotFoundException {
        Mockito.when(repository.existsById(anyInt())).thenReturn(false);
    
        ...
        CustomerNotFoundException thrown = Assertions.assertThrows(CustomerNotFoundException.class, () -> testService.createAccount(account));

        Assertions.assertEquals("the exception message", thrown.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing the same in the Service class, The test case is failing. 
While debugging, I could see the control never executes inside the methods in helper class. 

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected com.banking.bankingapp.common.exceptions.CustomerNotFoundException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Comment: Sounds like the helper class is accidentally a mock instead of a Spring Bean. Is it declared as mock anywhere in your test context? Do you import any test configuration, which in turn makes a mock of your helper class?